# Hardcode run-as encrypted credentials in Powershell

Tags: parameters, hashtable, powershell-2.0, runas

I finally got this powershell script to work with all your help!!!!

```
$line_array = @()
$multi_array = @()
[hashtable]$my_hash = @{}

foreach ($i in $args){
   $line_array+= $i.split(" ")
}

foreach ($j in $line_array){
    $multi_array += ,@($j.split("="))
}

foreach ($k in $multi_array){
    $my_hash.add($k[0],$k[1])
}

$Sender_IP = $my_hash.Get_Item("sender-ip")

$eventList = @()
Get-EventLog "Security" -computername $Sender_IP `
    | Where -FilterScript {$_.EventID -eq 4624 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[4].Length -gt 10 -and $_.ReplacementStrings[5] -notlike "*$"} `
    | Select-Object -First 2 `
    | foreach-Object {
        $row = "" | Select UserName, LoginTime
        $row.UserName = $_.ReplacementStrings[5]
        $row.LoginTime = $_.TimeGenerated
        $eventList += $row
        }
$userId = $eventList[0].UserName
$userId
```

Can be invoked with

```
.\FOO.ps1 sender-ip=10.2.23.40 sender-name=joe sender-id=djoe
```

But now, I need to prepare it for this third-party program to invoke it. The script will produce output, (i.e. for a given IP address find last user logged on) only if it runs as a service account. This means that when I test the script, I can select 'Run-As' and enter in service account credentials.

The third-party program doesn't run using service credentials, which means I must do it on the program side.

How to make this program run-as a service account automatically?
How would I hardcode this? 
And username and password must be encrypted.

Can you point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:** I am reading this link, http://blogs.technet.com/b/robcost/archive/2008/05/01/powershell-tip-storing-and-using-password-credentials.aspx

And it shows how to pump in an encrypted password into a file

```
PS C:\> read-host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\cred.txt
```

And then bring it back to script

```
PS C:\> $password = get-content C:\cred.txt | convertto-securestring
```

And create credential object

```
PS C:\> $credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "myusername",$password
```

But I am still trying to figure out how to make the script run using these credentials

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that crucial point (point, where you use alternate credentials) is Get-EventLog cmdlet. This cmdlet does not support -Credential, but you can use Get-WinEvent instead. It would probably mean that you need to change where filter. I would suggest also moving part (all?) of the filter to Get-WinEvent cmdlet:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ 
    ID = 4624
    LogName = 'Security' 
} -ComputerName $Sender_IP -Credential $Credential
```

BTW: If you store credentials using convertTo/From-SecureString they will work only for account that is performing the operation (so if you 3rd party tool runs under different credentials, it won't be able to process credentials that you produced).